# Pandas Dataframe: How to create a column of incremental unique value count of another column

Tags: python, pandas, count

Consider the sample dataframe ('value' column is of no significance here):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':list('AABBBC'), 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

[image: df]

What I want is a column to count the unique value of only the 'key' column, the caveat being value count will be incrementally ascending and the count will only go up if the cell value hasn't appeared in previous rows. So here "A" will be assigned value 1, "B" 2 and "C" 3.

The desired result looks like this:

[image: desired]

Right now I can only achieve this with a couple of steps:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('key').reset_index(drop = True).drop(columns = ['value'])
df1['count_unique'] = df1.index+1


pd.merge(df, df1.set_index(['key']), left_on = ['key'], right_index= True, how = 'left')
```

It doesn't look very Pythonic and is not the most efficient. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

```
df['count_unique'] = df['key'].factorize()[0] + 1
```

Output:

```
  key  value  count_unique
0   A      1             1
1   A      2             1
2   B      3             2
3   B      4             2
4   B      5             2
5   C      6             3
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for this. I should've used a group of columns as my example. Can this be applied to unique values of multiple columns? Thanks!

Comment: @BowenLiu look at the dup link. `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).ngroup()`.

Comment: Marvelous. I've struggled for a couple of hours to find the succinct methods. And you gave them to me on a silver platter. Thank you so much Quang!

Comment: Just a following question: why doesn't `ngroup` seem to return result in an ascending order for me even when I explicitly passed `ascending = True'?

Comment: pass `sort=False` in `groupby`. Without this, `groupby` will sort the data by key columns and enumerate the groups according to this order.

Comment: Works like a charm! Really appreciate it Quang.